# Identifying issue with simple Apache Beam setup

Tags: python, tensorflow, apache-beam

I am new to learning Apache Beam and have had trouble with performance. Despite that I am using parallelizable operations + converting to PCollections, Beam is incredibly slow. Furthermore, when running on larger amounts of data (i.e., more than a few hundred thousand rows) I get issues around data size (i.e., `exceeds maximum protobuf size of 2GB` errors for operations).

I am just trying to reproduce code from another research group (copied from an online reproduction of the [C4 dataset](https://github.com/tensorflow/datasets/blame/master/tensorflow_datasets/text/c4_utils.py)), so while the individual operations are likely ok, I am worried about a simple setup issue that I can't figure out.

I think the issue might be with starting the pipeline, or with how I am passing data to the pipeline. Help would be greatly appreciated! Here is a skeleton of my code:

```py
  pipeline = beam.Pipeline()
  line_to_selected_url = (
      pipeline
      | beam.Create(pages) # pages is entirely Python objects: a list of tuples (string, dict)
      | beam.FlatMap(_emit_url_to_lines) # this is copied so it should be ok
      | beam.combiners.Top.PerKey(1, key=_hash_text, reverse=True)) #  # this is copied so it should be ok

  lines_to_keep = line_to_selected_url | beam.Map(lambda x: (x[1][0], x[0]))

  final_docs = ({ "features": pages, "lines": lines_to_keep }
                | "group_features_and_lines_by_url" >> beam.CoGroupByKey()
                | beam.FlatMap(
                    _remove_lines_from_text,
                    min_num_sentences=min_num_sentences)
                | beam.combiners.ToList())
  res = final_docs | ("Write to JSON" >> beam.Map(hacky_save))
  result = res.pipeline.run()
  result.wait_until_finish()
```

I think the issue could also lie with how I run the pipeline. To run the code I am passing the parameters: `--autoscalingAlgorithm=BASIC --maxWorkers=32` to the script (found in another Stackoverflow post).

Thank you so much in advance for any help!

Comment: Hi @Reginald, Are you using [Google Cloud DataFlow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow) to run the pipeline ?

Comment: @DhirajSingh: No, I am using my own machine!

Comment: Python DirectRunner is usually used to test and develop a local Beam pipeline. To run this with the large data, you should choose other runners, such as DataflowRunner. 

In your pipeline, `beam.combiners.ToList()` could be expensive since it condenses a PCollection into a single list. Can you avoid this?

Answer (score 0):

The configuration you're passing as command-line arguments might be the problem, you can fine-tune these values based on your specific use case and the resources available in your environment.

You can specify the machine type and size for your workers: "--workerMachineType." and also configure the initial number of workers: "--numWorkers".

In addition to specifying the autoscaling algorithm, you can also define custom autoscaling policies to fine-tune how your pipeline scales based on specific metrics or conditions.